# Why is inserting a script in head with jQuery so strange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, head

If I confirm I've already got jQuery,

```
$('<script type="text/javascript"/>').text("alert('boo');").appendTo($("head"));
```

works as expected.  But there's no way to see the script in firebug or Chrome's dev tool.

Nobody recommends inserting a script that way and everyone says to

```
headtag=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
scripttag=document.createElement('script');
scripttag.type='text/javascript';
scripttag.innerHTML="alert('boo');";
headtag.appendChild(scripttag);
```

In that case, it *is* visible in firebug.  Why is the latter preferable to the former?  Why doesn't firebug show the script?

Comment: I wonder why anyone would use either of those two scenarios rather than just doing `alert('boo')`

Comment: If you want to add an external script to the page, you should be using jQuery's [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When jQuery deals with HTML text to be appended to the DOM, it always strips out `<script>` content first.  It evaluates the script after updating the DOM.